# Mono ignores existing file, throws error

Tags: c#, mono

I am trying to compile [this workspace](https://github.com/Sammi-Husky/Sm4sh-Tools) with Mono, specifically the Sm4shCommand/AnimCmd project. When I compile it with MonoDevelop, I get

```
/home/----------/Downloads/Sm4sh-Tools-master/AnimCmd/CSC: Error CS2001: Source file `System/Windows/Forms/HexBox/Forms/GotoDialog.designer.cs' could not be found (CS2001) (Sm4shCommand)
```

I get the same error when I try to compile it with xbuild.

The file it says doesn't exist is in the project. Is there a reason it isn't recognizing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are on Linux...

It that a file case issue that on Windows or OS-X you would not see, edit the `Sm4shCommand.csproj` file and change 
`GotoDialog.designer.cs` to `GotoDialog.Designer.cs`

```
./AnimCmd/System/Windows/Forms/HexBox/Forms/GotoDialog.Designer.cs

AnimCmd/Sm4shCommand.csproj:    <Compile Include="System\Windows\Forms\HexBox\Forms\GotoDialog.designer.cs">
```

Comment: I fixed the problem by just deleting the function and reference to the DLL, as it just set the file extensions to that program, and it wasn't needed on Linux.